# How can I add a <CreateButton> (seeding the foreign key) to a ReferenceManyField in admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have an edit form for a Post record, and I'm listing the Reviews associated with that Post in a ReferenceManyField/DataGrid (ie `<ReferenceManyField target="post_id" reference="reviews">`). Each Review has the foreign key `post_id` in the DB. This is all working fine, I have an edit and delete button for each Review row.

I need to add a 'Create Review' button for the Post form, such that the `post_id` field in the Create Review form is pre-populated with the current `id` of the Post. I'm not very expert in React/Redux.

Answer (score 3):

As @Gildas has suggested above, you need a custom component for that.

1) A custom create button that routes to a create page for the review. For this you should look at how the React Router Link component documentation as well as how Admin On Rest would allocate a route for instance /:reviewId/create

2) Create a custom input component that will prefill the ID when loaded. This should be part of the location key in the props passed to your page. Ask additional questions as comments and I will try and answer them.

React and Redux are really simple things when you get the hang of them

Comment: How can I call an API for that `id` and fill the default values in create form?

Comment: My guess is there's a good chunk of developers that barely scratched the surface of React and are already working with React-admin. For them, it would help plenty if you add a snippet how the custom component would look like And as a bonus (since it wasn't asked) also deal with the case when there are yet zero records found of what was referenced in which case its likely to add a special placeholder.

Comment: Here's a new question for that if you feel inclined to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995057/how-would-a-custom-component-using-referencemanyfield-look-like-that-adds-a-butt

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly for now: you'll have to create a custom component for that: [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component).

Someone tried to address this issue and even supplied a pull-request. Hopefully we'll be able to merge it soon: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/744

Edit: this might help https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/07/09/react-admin-tutorials-form-for-related-records.html

Comment: I just found out that what your blog post is demonstrating is not working anymore with ra 2.9.0. The thing that's not working is that the Post field is not prefilled anymore in the CommentCreate component. See https://codesandbox.io/s/m7w28n9v58

Comment: I'll try to look into it soon. Probably not before next week though