# Using react-admin , How to create a comment from a post

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, api-platform.com, react-admin

I am using react-admin for a new project . One of the  challenge that I have right is to create something like **a comment from a post** . Here is the way I try to do it `<CreateButton basePath='/prescriptions' label="prescriptions" record={data}/>`. The problem That I am facing right is to use the **data record** in the **post form** to create the comment , that means I want to send the *post_id* with the *others data* from the commentForm . Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a <CreateButton> (seeding the foreign key) to a ReferenceManyField in admin-on-rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669460/how-can-i-add-a-createbutton-seeding-the-foreign-key-to-a-referencemanyfield)

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek how did you handle that? I can read in the SimpleForm the data that I pass in the CreateButton.

Comment: I'm still in the process of implementing it... Don't bother commenting on my planning or asking me for any promise that I will post an answer

Comment: I'm working on blog post about this. Stay tuned :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the post I mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025768/using-react-admin-how-to-create-a-comment-from-a-post#comment89126889_51025768) will be published soon. Besides, we're going to support this by default in `2.2.0`. In the mean time, here's what you can do:

```
import { parse } from "query-string";

const CommentCreate = props => {
    // Read the post_id from the location which is injected by React Router and passed to our component by react-admin automatically
    const { post_id: post_id_string } = parse(props.location.search);

    // Optional if you're not using integers as ids
    const post_id = post_id_string ? parseInt(post_id_string, 10) : '';

    return (
        <Create {...props}>
            <SimpleForm
                defaultValue={{ created_at: today, post_id }}
            >
                // ...
            </SimpleForm>
        </Create>
    );
}
```

Here's the button to create a new comment from an existing post:

```
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import ChatBubbleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChatBubble";
import { Button } from 'react-admin';

const AddNewCommentButton = ({ record }) => (
    <Button
        component={Link}
        to={{
            pathname: '/comments/create',
            search: `?post_id=${record.id}`
        }}
        label="Add a comment"
    >
        <ChatBubbleIcon />
    </Button>
);
```

And finally, how we use it alongside the `ReferenceManyField` in the post `Show` component (would work in `Edit` too):

```
const PostShow = props => (
    <Show {...props}>
        <TabbedShowLayout>
        ...
            <Tab label="Comments">
                <ReferenceManyField
                    addLabel={false}
                    reference="comments"
                    target="post_id"
                    sort={{ field: "created_at", order: "DESC" }}
                >
                    <Datagrid>
                        <DateField source="created_at" />
                        <TextField source="body" />
                        <EditButton />
                    </Datagrid>
                </ReferenceManyField>
                <AddNewCommentButton />
            </Tab>
        </TabbedShowLayout>
    </Show>
);
```

You can see this in action in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2393m2k5rj)

Edit: post published https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/07/09/react-admin-tutorials-form-for-related-records.html

Comment: Great stuff Gildas! Will the solution you provided here need to change once this feature is supported by default in 2.2?

Comment: Not all of it and it also depends on your needs. Create will be able to initialize its values from either the location state or search. However, we won't support default integer parsing of the id for instance, so this solution will still be relevant for some cases.

Comment: Post published, I added the link in my answer